# List tables of Database POSTGRES TYPE

Tags: sql, postgresql

how to list all tables name from all the database of postgres DB?

with schema name(database)

I have tried

```
select * 
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = 'public'
```

and

```
select  * 
from pg_tables 
where table_schema = 'public';
```

it only display the current select database columns;

Comment: That's not possible. You can't see table from a different database

Comment: That's not possible in POSTGRES u mean ? in MYSQL we are able to see all tables of the all databases using 

`select * from information_schema.tables`

Comment: Well MySQL's databases are really schemas.

Comment: i found something which can solve this problem to some extent
**dblink** [dblink-postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/contrib-dblink-function.html) 
thanks!! for ur response

Comment: If you use databases in MySQL to create separate namespaces you should use schemas in Postgres. That will be much more efficient.